# Unicode issue when creating PDF report using JasperReports via Java code

Tags: java, unicode, utf-8, jasper-reports, report

I develop Spring based Web application which uses JasperReports Library 5.0.0 to create reports. First I had Unicode characters issue when I made design of report using iReport 4.5.1. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5715473/jasper-reports-with-pdf-and-unicode-greek-characters) question here and solution was using font extensions. I did everything as described [here](http://mdahlman.wordpress.com/2010/05/28/jaspersoft-v3-7-font-extensions/) ("Create a report and specify fonts"). I installed "Tahoma" font to iReport, checked "Emded this font to PDF document" and selected "Identity-H (Unicode with horizontal writing)" as PDF encoding. It solved my issue when I executed and saved report as PDF using iReport. But when I used "jasper" file compiled by iReport in my Java code, I again got the issue related with Unicode characters. Generated report doesn't contain some of language specific characters.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution [here](http://jasperstarter.sourceforge.net/unicode-pdf-export.html#Using_a_font_outside_of_iReport).

- Just open the options dialog of iReports again.
- Select the iReport section (if not already selected).
- Click on the fonts tab.
- Select the previously installed font and click on the button "Export as extension".
- Chose a folder and filename ending with .jar

Now you have a ready to use font jar which can be used with JasperReports. Just add it to the classpath of your application.